# Binary Strings: How to determine if decomposition is ambiguous

Tags: combinatorics, regular-language

Let's say I have the following decomposition:

$$\{100,10011,00110\}^*$$

How would I determine if the decomposition is ambiguous or unambiguous?

Comment: In other words, you have a (right-) regular grammar $G$: $S\to 100 S, S\to 10011 S, S\to 00110 S, S\to\varepsilon$, and you want to determine whether $G$ is ambiguous — yes?

Comment: @BrianO Not sure what that really means but I want to determine if a set of binary strings is ambiguous.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what *that* really means, if not what I proposed. You want to know if some string in the language has two different derivations.

Comment: @BrianO So like if we say $A=\{0, 01\}$ and $B=\{0, 10\}$, $AB=\{00, 010, 0110\}$. And such $AB$ is ambiguous if there exists distinct pairs $(a_1, b_1)$ and $(a_2, b_2)$ in $A \times B$ with $a_1b_1=a_2b_2$.

Comment: @BrianO So I'm not entirely sure but what you're saying seems about right.

Comment: Yes we're saying the same thing :)

Comment: @BrianO Haha, okay. So any hints on this? I'm kind of lost. :(

Comment: There, I think I got it right :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L_0 = \{100, 10011, 00110\}$, and let $L= L_0^{*}$. Then $L$ is unambiguous:

By induction on length of $w\in L$, we show that $w$ has a unique decomposition into $100, 10011, 00110$.

**Base case:** $|w| \le 5$. Then $w$ cannot be of the form $xy$ for $x,y\in L_0$, otherwise its length would be at least 6.

If $w=\varepsilon$ then the result is trivially true.

Case 0: $w$ begins with $0$. Then $w = 00110$, and there is no other possibility.

Case 1: $w$ begins with $1$. Then we must have either $w = 100$ or $w=10011$, as there are no other possibilities.

**Induction step:** Assume the induction hypothesis (IH) that the result holds for strings of length less than $|w|$, and $|w| > 5$. Then $w = xy$ for some $x\in L_0$ and $y\in L$.

Case 1: $w$ begins with $1$. Then $w = 100 u y$, where $x = 100 u$ ($u$ might be empty$. Three subcases:

- If $uy$ begins with $11$, then $x = $10011$;
  * if $uy$ begins with $10$, then $x = $100$;
- if $uy$ begins with $0$,  then $x = $100$.

In each subcase, $x$ is uniquely determined. By IH, $y$ has a unique decomposition. Hence so does $w = xy$.

Case 0: $w$ begins with $0$. Then we must have $w = 00110 y$, and it's easy to see that there is no other way to decompose $00110$. Thus $y\in L$, so by IH $y$ has a unique decomposition, thus $w=00110 y$ does too.

Answer (score 0):

The question is to decide whether the set $X = \{100,10011,00110\}$ is a uniquely decodable [variable-length code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_code) or simply a *code*, in the sense of [1]. This question can be solved by using the [Sardinas–Patterson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardinas%E2%80%93Patterson_algorithm) but in this special instance, a much simpler proof is possible. Indeed $X$ is a *suffix code*, that is, a set of words none of which is a suffix of any other. And any suffix code is a code.

[1] J. Berstel, D. Perrin, C. Reutenauer (2010). *Codes and automata*. Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications 129. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. ISBN 978-0-521-88831-8. Zbl 1187.94001